# I can't change Cordova JAVA_HOME value

Tags: java, android, macos, cordova, ionic2

I recently upgraded my java version to 9. But now when I try to build for Android, I get

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
(node:87041) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

So I reinstalled jdk 1.8 and went into .bash_profile and changed JAVA_HOME to

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Which is what's returned when I use

```
>> source .bash_profile
>> echo $JAVA_HOME
```

However Cordova still gives the error above. Am I missing something?

EDIT: Output for /usr/libexec/java_home -V is

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
9.0.4, x86_64:  "Java SE 9.0.4" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_171, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_144, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 1):

The JDK is likely missing from your `$PATH`. Update your `PATH` to reflect the location of the jdk (normally for 9.0.4 it should be):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 9.0.4) # substitute version here
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If the export for `JAVA_HOME` does not work you can use the one you had, as it looks correct:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Add that to your `~/.bash_profile` and you should be back in business.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So I added those first two lines to my .bash_profile with version 1.8.0. I was then able to echo JAVA_HOME and got the correct path to jdk1.8.0. However when I run cordova build android, it still says my JAVA_HOME is jdk-9.0.4, stating "check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater"

Comment: Hmmm that's interesting, so the `JAVA_HOME` is reporting `1.8.0` and cordova is reporting `9.0.4`. Seems almost like it's cached or pulling the info from someplace else. Try restarting cordova, and don't forget to source `.bash_profile` first too.

Comment: It could also be for some reason Cordova is looking for just `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk` without the `/Contents/Home` — you might give that a try if things continue not to work.

Comment: I ran source .bash_profile in my project folder and now it says "could not determine java version from '9.0.4'. (Which I found means I need to upgrade my gradle) So it's a different output, but clearly still has the wrong JAVA_HOME value (because I want 1.8.0)

Comment: I'm finding that a lot of new bugs I'm running into are problems with JDK version 9+. A lot of solutions are saying to revert back to 1.8

Comment: Yes, I would recommend that. Other than that the docs more or less mention what you've already done: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-environment-variables. So maybe this is a bug you should report regarding the invalid jdk if 1.8.0 won't work. Maybe try uninstalling 9.0.4 too.